# Suggestion about search coincidences in string with PHP using REGEX

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to search this coincidence in a string:
1. I need to take only numbers after the chracter '@' as long as this coincidence has not spaces, for example:

String = 'This is a test **@VVC345RR,** text, and more text 12345'; 
I want to take only this from my string -> **345**.

My example:

```
$s = '\"access_token=103782364732640461|2. myemail@domain1.com ZmElnDTiZlkgXbT8e3 @DD234 4Jrw__.3600.1281891600-10000186237005';
$matches = array();
$s = preg_match('/@([0-9]+)/', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This only works when I have one @ and numbers.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
@\D*\K(\d+)
```

Accomplishes what you want?

This will look for an `@`, any non-numbers, and then capture the numbers. The `\K` ignores the early match.

https://regex101.com/r/gNTccx/1/

I'm unclear what you mean by `has not spaces`, there are no spaces in the example string.